# ILMerge commercial use questions

Tags: c#, vb.net, ilmerge

I recently work on a commercial project using vb.net code. Since the project needs some managed Dlls and I want to merge Dlls into the main assembly，I use the ILmerge and it works fine. However,since my project is a commercial project and the assembly will be distributed to the end users,I'm afraid there's a license or copyright problem when using ILmerge. I have read the license and only find the following statements related to my problem:

> 4.         NO RENTAL/COMMERCIAL HOSTING. You may not rent, lease, lend or provide commercial hosting services with the Software.

Then I think if there's no code written by ILmerge in my assembly (for example,ILMerge only merge my Dlls mechanically.)I can use this software with no problem. But I'm not sure how ILmerge works and whether my idea is correct or not.

Does anyone knows exactly in what condition I can use the ILMerge for commercial use without copyright(license) problem?

Thanks

Comment: Isnt it just saying you can't for example create a website that hosts ILMerge or rent it out.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place for legal advice. I am not a lawyer and I'm not giving legal advice here, but my understanding of these kinds of clauses is that they apply to the use of the software itself in something you charge money for, not the use of the software to _build_ something you charge money for. Similar to compilers, IDEs, etc. You can't rent out your copy of Visual Studio, but you can use it to write software that you rent out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for lawyers, not programmers.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you，I' ll ask someone who professional knows this somewhere.I'm sorry for this off-topic question.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge/blob/master/LICENSE